# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty e^{-b\left(\frac{r^2}{a^2}+1\right)^\frac{-\gamma}{2}}\left (\frac{r^2}{a^2}+1\right)^\frac{-\gamma}{2} r^2 dr $

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm working on research in astrophysics related to determining the ages of stellar nurseries. I've got the numerical solution, but need an analytic solution to the integral below in order to better illustrate the behavior of the key parameters.

The problem is, after 3 days of trying, I'm no closer to a solution! Can anyone help me solve this?

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-b\left(\frac{r^2}{a^2}+1\right)^\frac{-\gamma}{2}} \left(\frac{r^2}{a^2}+1\right)^\frac{-\gamma}{2} r^2 dr
$$

where $a,b,\gamma$ are real, positive constants and $\gamma > 4$.

$\gamma$ is the key here. I would love to have a solution for general values of $\gamma$, but it would be enough for me to just have solutions for some two specific values of $\gamma$ for comparison.

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it very much.

Or if anyone can say with certainty that the integral is not solvable, then at least I can move on.

Comment: Pardon my terminology then; can you help me "evaluate" the integral?

Comment: What numerical solution do you have? According to Maple, the integral diverges when $a=b=1$ and $\gamma=3$.

Comment: Actually I never tried $\gamma = 3$ in my model, it probably doesn't converge there. All the clouds in my dataset have $4 < \gamma < 6$. So that's the only range of $\gamma$ values I've tried. Typically, $0 < r^2/a^2 < 20$, and $0 < b(r^2/a^2+1)^{\gamma/2} < 10 $

Comment: @Marko, how can those bounds be true for finite $a,b,\gamma$ when $r\rightarrow \infty$ in accordance with the integration limits? I am guessing you missed the minus sign of $\gamma$ in the second in which case I can see how that might hold, but the first inequality seems strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define:
$$f(a,b,\gamma)=\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{{\rm e}^{-b \left( {\frac {{r}^{2}}{{a}^{2}}}+1
 \right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma\, n}}} \left( {\frac {{r}^{2}}{{a}^{2}}}+1 \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}\gamma\, n}{r}^{2}{dr}$$

then after the variable change $R=ra$ you have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(a,b,\gamma)&={a}^{3}{\frac {\partial }{\partial b}}\int _{0}^{
\infty }\!-\mathrm{exp}\left[{-b \left( {R}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma\, }}\right]{R}^{2}{dR}\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{a}^{3}}{n!}{\frac {\partial }{\partial b}}\int _{0}^{
\infty }\!(-b)^n{\left( {R}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma\, n}}{R}^{2}{dR}\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-b)^{n-1}\frac{{a}^{3}}{(n-1)!}\int _{0}^{
\infty }\!{\left( {R}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma\, n}}{R}^{2}{dR}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and the integral can be recognised as the [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) function:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int _{0}^{\infty }\! \left( {R}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-\frac{1}{2}\gamma\, n}{R}^{2}{dR}&=\frac{1}{2}\,\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\sqrt {s}}{ \left( s+1 \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}\,\gamma\, n}}}{ds}\quad:R=\sqrt{s}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\,\beta \!\left( \frac{3}{2},-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\,\gamma\,n \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\,{\frac {\sqrt {\pi }\Gamma  \left( -\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\,\gamma n \right) }{\Gamma 
 \left( \frac{1}{2}\,\gamma\, n \right) }}
\end{aligned}
$$
hence:

> $$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{{\rm e}^{-b \left( {\frac {{r}^{2}}{{a}^{2}}}+1
>  \right) ^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}}}} \left( {\frac {{r}^{2}}{{a}^{2}}}+1 \right) ^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}}{r}^{2}{dr}=\frac{{a}^{3}\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \,\Gamma  \left( -\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\gamma n \right) }{
> \Gamma  \left( \frac{1}{2}\gamma\,n \right) \Gamma(n)}}\left( -b
>  \right) ^{n-1}$$

An example for $\gamma=4$ will give closed form in terms of the [generalized Hypergeometric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) function:
$$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{{\rm e}^{- \left( {r}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-2}}}{r}^{
2} \left( {r}^{2}+1 \right) ^{-2}{dr}=a^3\frac{\pi}{4}\,
{\mbox{$_2$F$_2$}\!\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};\,1,\frac{3}{2};\,-b\right)}$$

Comment: Yeah, expanding the exponential into a series was the first thing I tried. I guess I should've been more specific in my question. I need an answer that is in a form that is "human-readable" in the sense that I need to compare the behaviors of the various constants with two other non-trivial equations. And I have no idea how to manipulate the hyper-geometric function to do that. I was hoping someone would come up with an answer in a different form.

Comment: But I think this is the best possible way to evaluate this integral, I don't think there's any other way to express the hyper geometric function. Thank you.